# Is it possible to get a specific wildfly version from Dockerhub?

Tags: docker, wildfly, wildfly-18

We are deploying our application war file on the `wildfly-18` and we would like to dockerize the application for that, I want to download the wildfly-18 image from the dockerhub, but when I use `jboss/wildfly` gives me the latest wildfly which I don't want. I would like to use strictly wildfly-18. Is it possible to get the wildfly-18? If no, how can I get the wildfly-18?
I've searched over the internet, but couldn't find anything.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news!  Looks like they have tags for those versions in Dockerhub.  Both v18.0.0 and v18.0.1.  Will either of these work for you?

`docker pull jboss/wildfly:18.0.0.Final`

`docker pull jboss/wildfly:18.0.1.Final`

You can find the tags for these as well as many other versions of `jboss/wildfly` [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/tags).

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned this before. By default it's downloading with openjdk 11. Is it possible to have downloaded with openjdk-13?

Comment: I doubt you can download it with openjdk-13 installed already. But depending on what they chose for a base image, you may be able to install openjdk-13 in an image that extends off of theirs. You can try something like `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-13-jdk` in your Dockerfike